# Slicing a python string

Tags: python, string, list, slice

I have a list:

```
rows=['1\t0.00032822\n', '2\t0.00029311\n', '3\t0.0002048\n',...]
```

and i want to have a list with the numbers only:

```
['0.00032822', '0.00029311', '0.0002048',...].
```

Something like:

```
list = [sliceAppropiate(x) for x in rows]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> rows = ['1\t0.00032822\n', '2\t0.00029311\n', '3\t0.0002048\n'] 
>>> [r.split()[1] for r in rows]
['0.00032822', '0.00029311', '0.0002048']
```

What this does is:

- Go through each item in `rows` in turn,
- Give it the name `r`,
- Split each `r` into a list with [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), by cutting at whitespace (which can be spaces, tabs or newlines),
- Take item 1 from that list (where item 0 is the first one, because Python uses [zero-based indexing](https://plus.google.com/115212051037621986145/posts/YTUxbXYZyfi)).

Comment: So, split by default "splits" in numbers! Nice!

Comment: @JohnZobolas Actually it splits on whitespace - from the docs I linked to: "If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace."

Comment: @JohnZobolas split splits on whitespace, which \t and \n are.

Comment: Thanks Zero and Aaron! I also used something like this to have the sum of the list of numbers: sum([(float) (r.split()[1]) for r in rows])

Comment: @JohnZobolas great! You can make that a little more efficient and readable by dropping the parentheses around `float`, and the square brackets around the listcomp (turning into a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)): `sum(float(r.split()[1]) for r in rows)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple code that do it for you:

```
list = []
for i in range(len(rows)): # from 0 to len(rows) - 1
    list[i] = rows[i].split('\t')[1]
```

If need float numbers use float function:

```
float(rows[i].split('\t')[1])
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe that the answer with the list comprehension is better-more compact and easy to understand!